# Flutter SDK path changed after running the app on Windows after MacOS

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I have been playing around with some flutter basics on Windows then wanted to test it on Mac. I did successfully but when I got back again to windows to work on it again I found out that VSCode changed Flutter SDK path in the whole project. The Flutter SDK path on windows is

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\sdk\flutter
```

And on Mac

```
/Users/USERNAME/Downloads/flutter
```

When I tried to test it again on Windows after Mac I got so many errors like this

```
 Error: Error when reading '/Users/USERNAME/Downloads/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/material.dart': The system cannot find the path specified.
```

I run `flutter doctor` and got this

[image]

When I searched for the path of Flutter SDK on Mac in the project I found this

[image]

I searched for `dart.flutterSdkPath` in the settings and changed the path but that didn't fix this issue

```
"dart.flutterSdkPath": "C:/Users/USERNAME/Documents/sdk/flutter"
```

so I had to use search and replace tool to replace the path of Mac to the path of Windows in all of these files. It worked but how can I prevent changing the SDK path in the project every time I switch between Windows and Mac?

Answer (score 1):

All those file that you mentioned should be ignored already on the `.gitignore` created by the flutter create command. It will be generated automatically when you build your project.

In case you don't have it, here is the default `.gitignore` file

```
# Miscellaneous
*.class
*.log
*.pyc
*.swp
.DS_Store
.atom/
.buildlog/
.history
.svn/

# IntelliJ related
*.iml
*.ipr
*.iws
.idea/

# The .vscode folder contains launch configuration and tasks you configure in
# VS Code which you may wish to be included in version control, so this line
# is commented out by default.
#.vscode/

# Flutter/Dart/Pub related
**/doc/api/
**/ios/Flutter/.last_build_id
.dart_tool/
.flutter-plugins
.flutter-plugins-dependencies
.packages
.pub-cache/
.pub/
/build/

# Web related
lib/generated_plugin_registrant.dart

# Symbolication related
app.*.symbols

# Obfuscation related
app.*.map.json

# Android Studio will place build artifacts here
/android/app/debug
/android/app/profile
/android/app/release
```

After changing the `.gitignore` files, make sure to run `git rm -r --cached .` before `git add .` to ensure Git is tracking the right files.